# moving rows in 2D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array, 2d

I currently have a 2d array like this

```
array = [ [a1, a2, a3, a4],
          [b1, b2, b3, b4],
          [c1, c2, c3, c4],
          [d1, d2, d3, d4],
        ]
```

want I want to do is change the array to this:

```
array = [ [b1, b2, b3, b4],
          [c1, c2, c3, c4],
          [d1, d2, d3, d4],
          [a1, a2, a3, a4],
        ]
```

I would preferably like a method where I can save the 'a' row to a variable and remove it from the 2d array, and then add it back to the end later.
thanks for any help.

Comment: Please show what you've tried. You seem to know the steps involved, what have you implemented from your research?

Comment: Since you already have a numpy array, `np.roll` would be the best solution in my opinion but that's not what you want I guess because of your condition you specified

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function that moves a row from a position to another one. Like the following:

```py
def move(matrix, src, dst):
    tmp = matrix[src]
    del matrix[src]
    matrix.insert(dst, tmp)
```

Then you wil have to call it with `src` (source index) and `dst` (destination index) with the proper values.

For example:

```py
matrix = [
    [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    [ 4, 5, 6 ],
    [ 7, 8, 9 ],
]

move(matrix, 1, 0)

# Now matrix is:
# [
#    [ 4, 5, 6 ],
#    [ 1, 2, 3 ],
#    [ 7, 8, 9 ],
# ]
```

Comment: for the remove src and dst do i do something like a[1] or a[1][1]?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. The above function does move a whole row (I added an example to my answer).

Comment: sorry, I didnt see your example. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
def alter(array,removeRow,addRow):
    temp = array[removeRow]
    del array[removeRow]
    array.insert(addRow,temp)
```

Comment: for the remove row and add row do i do something like a[1] or a[1][1]?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.